# Changing desktop background to the next available one

Tags: file-system, perl, child-process

How could I improve this working Perl script, which changes my desktop background to the next available one, without opening a terminal? Specifically, how could I iterate over my .fehbg and walls/ lazily, without reading them into arrays?  I couldn't find a way to do that; I need the `for` loops.

Other than that, are there any inefficiencies in my program, which could be spotted by a more experienced programmer?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# A background switching script which can be run from dmenu

use 5.18.2;
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

my @fehbg = ();
my @files = ();
open 'FEHFH', '</home/chummer/.fehbg';
while(<FEHFH>){
    @fehbg = split/'/;
}
close FEHFH;
my $current = basename($fehbg[-2]);
opendir WALLSDIR, '/home/chummer/pictures/walls';
foreach(readdir WALLSDIR){
    unless($_ eq '.' || $_ eq '..'){
    push(@files, $_);
}
}
closedir WALLSDIR;
for(my $i = 0; $i <= $#files; ++$i){
    if($current eq $files[$i]){
    if(exists($files[$i+1])){
        foreach($files[$i+1]){ s/\s+/\\ /g; }
    system"feh --bg-fill /home/chummer/pictures/walls/$files[$i+1]";
    last;
    }
    else{
        foreach($files[0]){ s/\s+/\\ /g; }
    system"feh --bg-fill /home/chummer/pictures/walls/$files[0]";
    last;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `while` to iterate over directory elements and skip reading them all at once into array,

```
opendir my $WALLSDIR, '/home/chummer/pictures/walls';
while (my $file = readdir($WALLSDIR)) {
    next if $file eq '.' or $file eq '..';

    # ..
}
```

Since you're not checking if `open()` or `opendir()` calls were successful at all, put

```
use autodie;
```

at beginning of your script, and exceptions with description will be thrown when some of these calls fails.

Stylistic remark, `my @fehbg = ();` is same as just `my @fehbg;`

Use lexical file-handles together with three argument `open` (also lexical dir-handle for `opendir`),

```
open my $FEHFH, '<', '/home/chummer/.fehbg';
```

Again stylistic remark,

```
for my $i (0 .. $#files)
```

is a more readable/simpler equivalent of,

```
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#files; ++$i)
```

Then `foreach($files[$i+1]){ s/\s+/\\ /g; }` is longer and less performant version of `$files[$i+1] =~ s/\s+/\\ /g;`